# Перевести координаты россреестра (EPSG:3395) в широту и долготу (EPSG:4326)?

Tags: api, gis

Координаты я беру [здесь](https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/#/search/56.97701855380439,60.57313985431199/17/@qih8n8v9?text=56.977092%2060.572856&type=1&inPoint=true&opened=66%3A36%3A102062%3A13). В адресной строке они есть. Далее, если посмотреть стек-трейс запросов, то можно [увидеть](https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/1/66:36:102062:13?date_format=%25c&_=1587711826223), что приезжают координаты в другой системе координат.

В сети нашёл, что кооринаты в долготе и широте -- это проекция EPSG:4326. То, что в росреестре, по идее, должно быть EPSG:3395. Нашёл [калькулятор](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3395&x=55.5854869&y=37.6315469). Но погрешность катастрофическая.

Подскажите, как перевести координаты из одной проекции в другую?

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь в названии вопроса формулировать основную часть вопроса, например вот так.

Comment: не знаю как насчет этих датумов, обычно выручала библиотека proj4, точнее ее порты - proj4j и proj4js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразования следующие:

```
def y2lat(y):
    return (2 * math.atan(math.exp(y / 6378137)) - math.pi / 2) / (
            math.pi / 180)


def x2lon(x):
    return x / (math.pi / 180.0) / 6378137.0
```

Взяты [отсюда](https://github.com/rendrom/rosreestr2coord/blob/b2019e8a10e41173f7d0d0296bb7458d19189cbe/rosreestr2coord/utils.py#L29)